# Python Argparse "radio" flags with default?

Tags: python, argparse

For example:

`example.py`

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Will take arguments... or none")

parser.add_argument("-a", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-b", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-c", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-d", action="store_true")

args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

I want example.py to set `a` to `True`, but only if either:

- The `-a` flag is used
- No flags are used

I tried messing around with

`parser.set_defaults(a=True, b=False)`

and

`parser.add_argument("-a", action="store_true", default=True)`

but they will set `a` to `True` even if I decide to use the `b` flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes using the default values will set a to True even other arguments are specified. This will violate your second requirement, following is a simple fix with a naive condition checking.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Will take arguments... or none")

parser.add_argument("-a", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-b", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-c", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-d", action="store_true")

args = parser.parse_args()
if not (args.b or args.c or args.d):
    args.a=True
print args
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a 'radio button' effect - choosing just one of several alternatives.  An alternative to a set of flags would be an argument with choices.

```
parser.add_argument('flag', choices=['a','b','c','d'], default='a', nargs='?')
```

You can check the result in `args.flag`, which will be one of 4 strings.

Obviously the positional argument couple replaced by a flag, e.g. `-f`.

Comment: Yes, very true. I eventually found another solution, which I'll post here soon.

Answer (score 1):

I went for the following solution:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Will take arguments... or none")

lettergroup = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

lettergroup.add_argument("-a", action="store_const", dest="letter", const="a", default="a")
lettergroup.add_argument("-b", action="store_const", dest="letter", const="b")
lettergroup.add_argument("-c", action="store_const", dest="letter", const="c")
lettergroup.add_argument("-d", action="store_const", dest="letter", const="d")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now, the value is stored in `args.letter`. If no flag is called, `args.letter` will have the value `a`. If two flags are called at the same time, the parser will throw an error.

Just another way to solve this problem.